# Which Matplotlib format specifier do I use for contour labels to be as terse as possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, number-formatting

So I'm doing a contour plot with inline labels for the contours. The labels should be as terse as possible. So far I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
CS = plt.contour(dat, [2e6, 5e8, 8e11], norm = LogNorm(vmin=cutoff))
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=9, inline=1, fmt="%.0g")
```

Which leads to labels like

> 2e-06 5e+08 8e+11

I think there should be no leading zeros in the exponent and the sing should be omitted, if the exponent is positive, i.e. above example should read:

> 2e-6 5e8 2e11

What format specifier or formatter function can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to format the contour labels (clabels) to your wishes, you may use a formatter instance as argument to `fmt`.

For example to have nicely looking labels you could use a `LogFormatterSciNotation`, which gives

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-6,7, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
dat = np.exp(-(X-2)**2-(Y-2)**2)*  15e12

cutoff = 1e6
CS = plt.contour(dat, [2e6, 5e8, 8e11], norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=cutoff))
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation()
fmt.create_dummy_axis()
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=9, inline=1, fmt=fmt)

plt.show()
```

Here the clabels are a bit larger, so may not actually correspond to what is needed. Instead of a Formatter instance, one could also just use a normal function which takes a value as input and returns a formatted string.

So below is a function that would format the numbers by removing plus signs and unnecessary zeros:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-6,7, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
dat = np.exp(-(X-2)**2-(Y-2)**2)*  15e12

cutoff = 1e6
CS = plt.contour(dat, [2e6, 5e8, 8e11], norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=cutoff))

def func(x):
    s = "%.0g" % x
    if "e" in s:
        tup = s.split('e')
        significand = tup[0].rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
        sign = tup[1][0].replace('+', '')
        exponent = tup[1][1:].lstrip('0')
        s = ('%se%s%s' % (significand, sign, exponent)).rstrip('e')    
    return s

plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=9, inline=1, fmt=func) 

plt.show()
```

[image]